# ie7 css with div align right in TD

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

The markup below produces 2 lines of text, with the 2nd line of text centred and an image in the bottom right on the 2nd line. At least it does in Firefox and ie8. In ie7 it adds a line-break and the image appears on a 3rd line. I've tried all sorts of things without success and the ie Developer Tool is so not very useful.

How do I get it to appear properly (like ie8) in ie7?

```
<table>
    <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            Hi
            <div style="float:right; background-image:url('aaa.png'); height:16px; width:16px;">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is just a very simplified version of what I have; I need the table structure, so please don't suggest changing it to a series of divs :)

Comment: I know you said about not suggesting changing it to a series of divs, but I used to be just like you and used tables for everything - layout, data, the works... However once you get the hang of using clears and floats it becomes a lot easier. Spend some time working out how clear / float works and try doing various layouts - such as two column, three column, product details (like you see on lots of websites with the image top left, details to the right of that and the description below). You should soon get the hang of it.

Comment: @Clarkey: I agree and I've been trying to use divs more often, however this particular markup is for a horribly complicated project: Building a office-like ribbon bar in html. It works fine in ie8 so I don't want to rewrite the 800 lines of css and 400 lines of markup just to accommodate ie7 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting any width on the table, so it will be as small as possible to fit the contents.

Try also putting "Hi" in a div (or span) with float left. This should work, in theory.

You may want to put both sides in spans actually, come to think of it, as divs default to the size of their parent (-border, margin and padding).

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Richard

Edit: The actual answer to this is to set the position of the right-floated div to absolute, height / width to 16px, top and right to 0. Also remove the `float: right`. (I have left my original answer there so that a) the comments make sense and b) anyone who reads this in the future knows that the original answer didn't work).

Comment: I've tried the "Hi" in a div floating left and it ended up left-aligned. I would like the text centre-aligned.

Comment: Ah yeah forgot about the centre thing... give me a few minutes to think about it - if I think of anything then I will let you know.

Comment: It just occurred to me - have you tried applying the text-align: center on the left-floated div?

Comment: You could also try setting the right-floated div to position absolute, width 16px, height 16px, right 0px and top 0px. This should work, so long as the parent is set to position relative.

Comment: Champion! Adding position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; to the div and position: relative; to the TD styles fixed it!

Comment: Thought it might. Dunno why I didn't think of it before. Make sure you check it in other browsers too - there may also be some differences using that technique...

Comment: Works in ie7, ie8 and firefox so I'm happy with that! Can you edit your answer to include the solution please?

Comment: Ok the solution has been added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reversing the order of the "Hi" and the `<div>`:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>blah blah blah blah</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <div style="float:right; background-color: #f00; height:16px; width:16px;"></div>
            Hi
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This looks the the same in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE7, IE8, and Opera. Chrome, Safari, and Firefox render both versions the same; IE7 and Opera render the original version with the same problem.

I changed the `background-image` to `background-color` so I could see what was going on, shouldn't have any effect on the rendering but IE7 is rather clever at making a mess of things so maybe not.

Comment: We actually got this to work - see the comments on my answer. He ended up using position absolute, top 0 and right 0.

Comment: Nice, sorting out IE7 problems usually ends up like that: try a bunch of half-random `margin`/`padding`/`display`/`position` fiddling until it works then hit the pub erase the memories.

Comment: Yeah... usually I hit the pub and erase the memories before I find the solution lol... by pub I mean the 2 litre bottles of cider I store under my desk lol

Comment: were? They have probably been drunk since birth... Wish I was like that... love the feeling of being tipsy when working!